# How can I change colorscale for colorbar with R-Plotly?

Tags: r, r-plotly

I am trying to create a plotly scatterplot with color as my third dimension. I am able to change my colorscale as I like, but I have been unable to change my colorbar to match the colorscale of the scatterplot points (the colorbar stays 'Viridis' even when I specify the colorscale = 'Hot').

```
library(plotly)

data = iris

p = plot_ly(data,
                x=~ Sepal.Length,
                y=~ Sepal.Width,
                type = 'scatter',
                mode = 'markers',
                marker = list(
                  size=10,
                  opacity=.9,
                  colorscale='Hot'),
                color=~Petal.Length)

colorbar(p)
```

I would expect the colorbar to match the specified colorscale, but it remains 'Viridis'.

[image: The colorbar should match the specified colorscale = 'Hot' but it still displays 'Viridis']

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible by either posting a [mcve] of your dataset using `dput`, or rewriting your example code to use a built-in dataset like `iris` or `mtcars`? A reproducible example makes it much more likely that you'll get a high-quality answer

Comment: Yes, of course. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 7):

I am not a plotly expert, so I'm not sure of the underlying problem, but I can fix the problem by moving the `color=` and `colorbar=` definitions inside the `marker=` argument:

```
plot_ly(data,
        x=~ Sepal.Length,
        y=~ Sepal.Width,
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'markers',
        marker = list(
            color=~Petal.Length,
            size=10,
            opacity=.9,
            colorscale='Hot',
            colorbar=list(
                title='Colorbar'
            )
        )
)
```

[image]

Alternately, if you define your color scale with the `colors=` argument, instead of `colorscale=`, it will work as desired. The downside is that you have to use:

> Either a colorbrewer2.org palette name (e.g. "YlOrRd" or "Blues"), or a vector of colors to interpolate in hexadecimal "#RRGGBB" format, or a color interpolation function like colorRamp()

```
p = plot_ly(data,
            x=~ Sepal.Length,
            y=~ Sepal.Width,
            type = 'scatter',
            mode = 'markers',
            marker = list(
                size=10,
                opacity=.9),
            color=~Petal.Length,
            colors = 'Blues'
)

colorbar(p)
```

[image]

`'Blues'` is a colorbrewer scale. You can also use color scales from the `viridis` package (see `?viridisLite::viridis`), like:

```
# note that you need to provide an n= argument >= the number of colors needed
viridis::inferno(99)
```